# Call muliple regular expression extractor's reference name in thread group in Jmeter and run with a for loop controller

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, performance-testing

Use regular expression in loop to extract multiple values from api.

Pls suggest

Answer (score 2):

JMeter Variables are local to current thread only, if you need to access them from other thread or thread group you need to convert them into JMeter Properties. JMeter properties are global for the whole [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) so once set you can access them from anywhere.

1. If you just need to convert a JMeter Variable into a JMeter Property you can use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) to set the property value and [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) functions to read the value in another Thread Group.
2. If your test logic is more complex, i.e. you don't want to take any actions in 2nd thred group until specified JMeter Variable value exists you can use [Inter-Thread Communication](http://Inter-Thread%20Communication) plugin to pass variables values across threads and thread groups. Check out [SynchronizationPluginsExample](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx) for a live use case.

   You can install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin using JMeter Plugins Manager.

   [image: JMeter Inter Thread Communication]

Comment: How to use setproperty function ?

Comment: As simple as `${__setProperty(foo,bar,)}` where `foo` is desired property name and `bar` is property value (can be a JMeter Variable as well). See https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rx4B.png for example use case and [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) for more detailed information if required.

Comment: I tried  and I got it  executed but did not give expected result.